# Google cloud SQL connection

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to connect to google cloud SQL. I was able to successfully do that a couple of days ago but right now I am facing some issues with that.
The problem that is occurring is

Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is`com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.

since it automatically loads com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver I am getting the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:676)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:663)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:653)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:638)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:606)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:1837)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:1653)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:662)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:352)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:221)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
    at com.example.endpoints.insertUser.doPost(insertUser.java:160)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:821)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:583)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1158)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1090)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:517)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:306)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceAndRun(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:654)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:572)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

**Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory cannot be cast to com.mysql.cj.api.io.SocketFactory**


    at com.mysql.cj.core.io.AbstractSocketConnection.createSocketFactory(AbstractSocketConnection.java:129)
    at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.io.MysqlaSocketConnection.connect(MysqlaSocketConnection.java:56)
    at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.MysqlaSession.connect(MysqlaSession.java:144)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:1783)
    ... 33 more
```

check the bold part....

the url I am using to make connection is this:-

```
"jdbc:mysql://google/*****?cloudSqlInstance=******&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory&user=****&password=****&useSSL=true"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you are using `mysql-socket-factory` which have class `com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory` implements `com.mysql.jdbc.SocketFactory`
Try this one: `mysql-socket-factory-connector-j-6`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the following dependencies

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>mysql</groupId>
  <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
  <version>*.*.*</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.cloud.sql</groupId>
  <artifactId>mysql-socket-factory</artifactId>
  <version>*.*.*</version>
</dependency>
```

use this starter instead

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-sql-mysql</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a Very similar issue that may have the same root cause

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create socket factory 'com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory' due to underlying exception: 
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory cannot be cast to com.mysql.jdbc.SocketFactory
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.createSocketFactory(MysqlIO.java:3324)
    ... 80 more
```

Which was very strange since I had everything working previously.

Turns out that my wifi connection was on the wrong network and I had no connectivity. When I fixed my network connection, the DB connection worked again. Tried enabling and disabling wifi to be sure. Yep, very confusing error for the actual problem.

Hope this helps out someone with the same issue.